# How to add watermark while using mergeSegmentsUsingPreset for SCRecorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-recording

I've asked before on how to add a watermark without using an Image and it got closed. My question now is in VideoConfiguration you can set a watermark but whenever I export the video the watermark is not added. How could I achieve this if I were to use mergeSegmentsWithPreset to export the video instead on the SCAssetExportSession route?

Also any ideas on how I can implement a running timer as watermark for my video? I need to have timestamp of some sort added as watermark and not just an some text.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the image working, you need to set the `watermarkFrame`

```
exportSession.videoConfiguration.watermarkFrame = someFrame;
```